# Converting OOP PHP to Angular: Class Inheritance

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, oop

As I continue to learn how to build my sites in Angular, one issue I'm having a lot of trouble with is how to get a view to behave a certain way based on the controller.

I have a site for playing pen-and-paper RPGs via play-by-post. In PHP, I have a "character" class, which has some top level functions for display. I have other classes that extend from that class, based on the type of game, and sometimes classes extending from those.

One example is that the vast majority of RPGs have stats. In a D20 based game, they tend to be a common set of six. In Savage World games they're different. On my display, with PHP, I have a function called "displayStats", and what it actually does/shows is different based on what child class calls it. In Angular, I can only think of doing this by having a bunch of different directives with different names, like `<stats-d20>` or `<stats-savage-worlds>`, but its messy.

So, like a class, can I have a directive `<stats>` that'll call something different based on different settings, other than putting in a bunch of `if` statements in the link function? A friend mentioned that you can assign a controller to a directive, but I haven't quite figured out how that'd help?

In general, I'm not seeing how to setup Angular code in a situation like this. I'm not seeing how to use the techniques/methods I learned through OOP here (and I'm guessing they're not directly useful), and its kinda annoying. Here I have this really great working OOP code to display stuff, and I'm struggling to think of how to do it without creating `<really-complex-directive-names>`. Or is that what I have to do? Use non-pretty names, harkening back to the days of multi-part variable names to categorize?

Comment: do `stats` have same data structure for different RPG's? If so is trivial to pass data into generic directive scope using attributes. If not same structure can add another attribute for `statType` and use a service to do whatever data munging is needed. Lots of flexibility in directives, just not clear what your specific issues are

Comment: Different data structures, different templates. I guess I'm not sure how to make a directive flexible without a bunch of if statements, nor how to use different templates based on need. I know how to make directives, pass attributes to do various things, isolate scopes, etc.

Comment: Need to see sample data comparison. Javascript (ES5) has no classes but certainly can be used for OOP

Comment: I'll try to put something together. It's less about the data structures and more about methodology. I'm just not understanding how/if to more accurately control directives and Google isn't yielding anything helpful. When you say data comparison, what do you mean? The different types of, for example, stats?

Comment: are structures the same...property names etc

Comment: Couldn't you load the character class into a service/factory?. You can use HTTP interceptors that would then query that service and redirect to the correct template? I'm about to pop out for a beer but if all you're looking for is view redirection based on the current players attributes then this is easy!